# Nothing to happen check root bash script

Tags: shell, unix

I'm trying to organize a root user check. If the program fails, we get exit 1. Nothing happens when the script is executed. Why?

Maybe fail in the script?

```
#!/bin/sh
[ "$(id -u)" = 0 ] || exit 1
echo "Running"
```

Comment: When I run this as root, it prints `Running`.

Comment: Are you saying nothing happens when it _is_ run as root, or nothing happens when it is _not_ run as root? How exactly are you testing it?

Comment: i got it!!! thx! I'm new to this business.